# How to create a mouse drag slider for HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web-applications

Many slider plugins that I have found are either only click to view next image or, if they do have mouse drag or touch drag capabilities, only allow images. Does anyone know of a plugin or possible way to code a mouse drag slider for any html elements? I'm specifically using an SVG, but it would be nice to have something in the future for sliding between div elements.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
    <ul>
        <li style="background-color: #F00"></li>
        <li style="background-color: #0F0"></li>
        <li style="background-color: #00F"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slider {
    width: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var slides = $('#slider ul').children().length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider').width();
    var min = 0;
    var max = -((slides - 1) * slideWidth);

    $("#slider ul").width(slides*slideWidth).draggable({
        axis: 'x',
        drag: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.position.left > min) ui.position.left = min;
            if (ui.position.left < max) ui.position.left = max;
        }
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/M8ydk/)**

Comment: How would I go about implementing the stop at a slide feature where one drags about half way and the slide sort of snaps into position.