# Create an effect like one slide reveals the other one with jquery

Tags: jquery, animation, slide

I wanted to create a slider with the following effect shown here https://codyhouse.co/demo/image-comparison-slider/index.html when clicking on the button slides are revaling each other.I created 2 buttons per slide and tried to do something like this

```
jQuery('#movetohappyscene').click(function(){
            jQuery('.badscene').animate({ marginLeft: '-1024px','z-index':'1'}, 2000);  
            jQuery('.happyscene').animate({ 
                marginLeft: '0px', 
                'z-index' : '2' 
            }, 2000);   
        });
        jQuery('#movetobadscene').click(function(){
            jQuery('.happyscene').animate({ 'z-index':'1'}, 2000);
            jQuery('.badscene').animate({'z-index':'2', marginLeft: '0px'},    2000);
        });


 <div class="slidecontainer">
    <div class="badscene">
        <a id="movetohappyscene">Click to show happy scene</a>
        <img src="img/badsceneempty.png">
    </div>
    <div class="happyscene">
        <a id="movetobadscene">Click to show sad scene</a>
         <img src="img/goodscene.png">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the updated  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anahitdev/upvtnco3/1/)

But the effect is not the same as in that slider.How I can customize my js so they will be similar?

Comment: Can you add the markup?

Comment: Yea some `html`  would be good on this!!

Comment: updated @Guruprasad Rao

Comment: If you notice the slider in the link provide by you.. its dragging effect of same button.. You want that effect or the effect you are trying to implement with 2 buttons?

Comment: I want both how will be easier to create with one buton or two @ Guruprasad Rao?

Comment: That depends on your requirement.. If you implement with one button with drag, then you might need `jquery-ui` too..

Comment: Yes I guess I need that, I tried with jquery ui slide effect but the result was not the same as I need.Can you help me how to do it ui?

Comment: Its a plugin right? why don't you implement that itself?

Comment: it has some cons, I integrated but when tryinhg to change the code with what I need it starting to work not properly - this is for the slider plugin, you mean with the ui?I havent used the drag button

Comment: Sorry!! I mis-read your question.. You just wanted the effect right? So is it something like **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/qxuzr2qr/)**?

Comment: Nearly yes I need animation with sliding right and left, it will make expression that one slide reveals the other one

Comment: This the voted code from this link and use it in your code...
[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032721/how-to-create-a-mouse-drag-slider-for-html-elements)

Comment: Yes thanks good one, also I customized my code, will use both your version too.

Answer (score 1):

**I have a similar example to your question, but i did this in pure css.**

```css
/**
 * Image slider with pure CSS
 */

.image-slider {
 position:relative;
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 0;
}


.image-slider > div {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
 width: 25px;
 max-width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 resize: horizontal;
}

/* Cross-browser resizer styling */
.image-slider > div:before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 right: 0; bottom: 0;
 width: 13px; height: 13px;
 padding: 5px;
 background: linear-gradient(-45deg, black 50%, transparent 0);
 background-clip: content-box;
 cursor: ew-resize;
 -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2px black);
 filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2px red);
}

.image-slider img {
 user-select: none;
 max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-slider">
  <div>
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/photoshop-face-before.jpg" />
  </div>
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/photoshop-face-after.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: oh very good example.Is there a way when pulling back to hide the second image fully?cause now some piece is shown @vickisys

Comment: when you are moving to the right and got the next image then going back so see the other one the piece of the previous one is shown